# icmp_echo_ignore_all doesn't get set

Tags: ping

I'm trying to set icmp_echo_ignore_all to 1, and I am able to do so using the following:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

I've also edited the sysctl.conf file and added:

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
```

and then I followed with this:

```
sysctl -p
```

Supposedly the last two steps would permanently set icmp_echo_ignore_all to 1, until the next time I enable it. Every time I reboot, though, it goes back to 0. Am I missing a step? I'm doing it on a virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me this did only get set after I issued sysctl -w to set the setting, as opposed to editing sysctl.conf manually.

I found that most other settings in sysctl.conf are picked up on reboot as sysctl.conf is linked also as /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf

For some reason this one isn't - or it is, but later in the boot process gets overwritten - so after a boot I usually manually issue sysctl -w again.